# React Hook "useState" or React Hook "useEffect" is called in function which is neither a React function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**TL;DR:** My GOAL is to separate the **API functions**, and import them when I need them. And then call them under a `componentDidMount` scenario. Also, I've been told that `async` and `await` shall be used with, since: `getCurrentPosition` is an asynchronous function.

---

Comment: can you please post the component that directly calls the hook

Comment: rename getLocation to useLocation and make the component where you use the hook a functional component: `const Weather = props => {useLocation();return jsx}`

Comment: I want to render Component on the page.

Comment: were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: Nope. Still stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the hints that you need to solve your problem are in the error code

1. Hooks or custom hooks are meant to be used within functional components
2. A custom hook is a hook that can be called like a function. It however must be prefixed with `use` to let react know that it is a custom hook

According to the above condition, your Weather component is a class component which either you need to convert to Functional component or avoid using geolocation as a custom hook

Secondly, since geoLocation is meant to be a custom hook you must call it `useGetLocation`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGetLocation } from './getlocation';

const Weather =  (props) =>  {
    const geoLocation = useGetLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = "Weather";
    }, []);

    return(
        <>
        <h1>Weather</h1>
        <h2>{React.version}</h2>
        </>
    );
}

export default Weather;
```

---

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const useGetLocation = () => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({});
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const successHandler = ({coords}) => {
        setPosition({
            latitude: coords.latitude,
            longitude: coords.longitude
        });
    };

    const errorHandler = (error) => { setError(error.message); };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
            setError("Geolocation might not be supported.");
            return;
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            successHandler, 
            errorHandler);

        return () => {}

    }, []);

    return [position, error];
};
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-rain-df63m?file=/src/App.js)**

---

Comment: Added a working codesandbox after fixing some typos

Comment: Please see my update. The error I keep getting is: "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons". But, see my edit above, regarding my GOAL. Thx.

Comment: @JohnSmith what is the result you expect to get. Also did you get a chance to see the demo, it works without throwing theerror you mentioned. Maybe you are on an older version of react or have different versions for react, react-dom. Please do let me know the specific issue.

Comment: I am using the latest **React v16.13.1**. I tested the demo, didn't see if it works, let me check again. I am not calling things the way you are calling them, I am using componentDidMount() and regular class that extends  React.Component.

Comment: @JohnSmith As I mentioned in my post, you cannot call hooks within class components. Also in your updated code, since `getCurrentPosition` function is async it won't return you the response immediately when you call it

Comment: I have updated my answer to show a sample code of how it would work if you used class component

Comment: Is there a way to make it, const geoLocation = getGeolocation(); and then use geoLocation.variable ?

Comment: I am getting: "Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function" ?

Comment: I am getting, "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function" ?

Comment: Please approve. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have to call the hook inside of a React functional component, and not a class.

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

> Hooks ... let you use state and other React features without writing a class.

and

> Only Call Hooks from React Functions

Secondly, change `getGeolocation` to `useGeolocation`

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook):

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” ...

If a function doesn't start with "use", React won't treat it as a hook and won't allow you to call hooks inside it

Comment: you can't call a hook in a class component. You can only call it in a functional component. You will likely need to rewrite your class component into a functional component

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke a hook inside a class. Hooks can only be called inside stateless components. If you want to have access to that information you should either transform it in a HOC or transform the class of the componentDidMount in a function.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-with-hooks-that-i-couldnt-with-classes

Comment: Explain more, please? I was trying to separate logic. And then invoke this from Weather.js which is a view sort of component, used in App.js Route.

Comment: If you want to use that hook you should either conver the app.js to a function something like this:
 function App () { return (<div> Stateless </div>)}

Comment: I am trying to call it from, `export default class Weather extends React.Component` component, which is Routed to via App.js.

Comment: Yeah like this const App = () => {};

Comment: If you not you can do something like this
const HOCLocation = Component => props => {
  const data = getLocation() // Your  hook
return <Component {...props} data=data />
}

Comment: Then where you call the App you just change the export default function App to this export default HOCLocation(App)